# How would you organize receiving 2 JSON files?

Tags: angularjs, json

I am curious how to best organize data using Angular with JSON API's.  The goal of my project is to have the First file GET and pushed into an array, then using 1 of the Key Values, it requests a Second JSON file based on the value I send back.  Then I can NG-Repeat (for example) over the Array based on this final return.

Here is my code so far:

```
app.factory('mtnFactory', ['$http', function($http){
  return {
          getMtns : function(){
            return $http.get('/js/mtnData.json');
          },
          getWeather: function(zipcode){
            return http.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/**KEY**/conditions/forecast/settings/q/'+zipcode+'.json')
    }
  }
}]);

app.controller('apresController', ['$scope', 'mtnFactory', function($scope, mtnFactory){

    $scope.mtnData = []
    var mtnPull = function(response){
        response.data.forEach(function(item){
            mtnFactory.getWeather(item.zip).then(weatherPull)
            $scope.mtnData.push(item)
        })
    }
    mtnFactory.getMtns().then(mtnPull)

    $scope.weatherData = []
    var weatherPull = function(response){
            $scope.weatherData.push(response.data)
    }
```

The kicker here is that because the "NAME" i want to use is in $scope.mtnData but the vital info I need is in the $scope.weatherData, I am not seeing how I can ng-repeat over 2 different $scope's.

So again, how would it be best to organize this info to easily access it, or should I push everything into 1 array?

I appreciate the input.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use single json array instead of two different. and use angularjs filter to get the selected json object list alone from the array. For Example

```
$scope.mtnData = []
var mtnPull = function(response){
    response.data.forEach(function(item){
        mtnFactory.getWeather(item.zip).then(weatherPull)
        $scope.mtnData.push(item)
    })
}
// Now consider $scope.mtnData is merged array with both datas
$Scope.weatherData = _.filter($scope.mtnData , function(data){ return mtnData.zipcode == zipcode});
```